# Reading mxArray in CUSP or in cuSPARSE

Tags: cuda, device, cusp-library

I am trying to read mxArray from matlab into my custom made .cu file.
I have two sparse matrices to operate on.
How do I read them inside cusp sparse matrices say A and B ( or in cuSPARSE matrices), so that I can perform operations and return them back to matlab. 
One idea that I could come up with is to write mxArrays in .mtx file and then read
from it. But again, are there any alternatives?

Further, I am trying understand the various CUSP mechanisms using the examples posted on its website.But every I try to compile and run the examples, I am getting the following error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of
'thrust::system::detail::bad_alloc'
  what():  N6thrust6system6detail9bad_allocE: CUDA driver version is
insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Abort
```

Here are the stuff that is installed on the machine that I am using.

```
CUDA   v4.2
Thrust v1.6
Cusp   v0.3
```

I am using GTX 480 with Linux x86_64 on my machine.
Strangely enough, code for device query is also returning this output.

```
CUDA Device Query...
There are 0 CUDA devices.

Press any key to exit...
```

I updated my drivers and SDK few days.
Not sure whats wrong.

I know, I am asking a lot in one questions but I am facing this problem from quite a while and upgrading and downgrading the drivers doesn't seem to solve.

Cheers

Comment: You should first fix the possible problems related with the drivers and the SDK and run the 'deviceQuery' example successfully.

Comment: @pQB Thanks for the reply...I updated the drivers and now examples are running fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is most revealing, "CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version".  You definitely need to update your driver.

I use CUSPARSE/CUSP through Jacket's Sparse Linear Algebra library.  It's been good, but I wish there were more sparse features available in CUSPARSE/CUSP.  I hear Jacket is going to get CULA Sparse into it soon, so that'll be nice.

Comment: With Jacket and CULA on mind, do you think, implementing a separate sparse matrix * sparse matrix based on SSMULT routine would make sense? since there would be divergence, and overhead of non linear access. Just wanted to know if I can multiply two sparse matrices from matlab on CUDA,efficiently...

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I updated the drivers and now examples are running fine.

Comment: Yes, I believe that Jacket can do SSMULT fast, though I've not benchmarked it myself. (can i get an upvote since i helped, i'm new to this?!)